# Pass Component Props to Object in Vue Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to pass props value in vue component to object as index like code below.

```
export default defineComponent({
  props:{
    pollId:{type: String}
  },
  data(){
    return{
      poll: polls[this.pollId]
    }
  }
})
```

But when I do this, I got error like these:
[image: error]

the compiler keeps assuming that my props are `undefined` even I've specified it above.

is there a way to fix this? without sacrificing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually as simple as adding `required` property in props

```
export default defineComponent({
  props:{
    pollId:{required:true,type: String}
  },
  data(){
    return{
      poll: polls[this.pollId]
    }
  }
})
```